# Tortoise SVN Crashed now it has an error

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

Ok I have apparently caused a large problem with my companies tortoise svn program, me and the admin are in the process of trying to fix it, but were not having much luck, here is my error message:

```
Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository 'file://file/directory/project/folder'
Berkeley DB error for filesystem '//file/directory/db' while opening
'nodes' table:
Invalid argument
bdb: file nodes (meta pgno = 0) has LSN [13005][1627022].
bdb: end of log is [13105][1531127]
bdb: \\file\directory\db\nodes: unexpected file type or format
```

This error occurs when i attempt to update, similar errors occur when I try to commit, or check out, also.

of course I have changed a couple of things in the error message, like the actuall directories we have here, but that is all I have changed.

the error occurred when I attempted to check something out, it then hung up, and i had to close it, then after this, it has been giving us this error.

Were running it on windows xp and the tortoise version number is 1.5.2

Our Admin tried using the svnadmin to repair the system, and when it told him it was complete it spit up a similar error once again. any one out there in tv land have any ideas what might be the problem here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TortoiseSVN. It's your repository that was corrupted, not the SVN client. I'd say restoring from backup is the easiest option here, unless you can somehow repair the DB.

Comment: would you know how something like this would be caused?

Answer (score 1):

The [`svnadmin`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnadmin) command line tool (not bundled with TortoiseSVN) has some subcommands to perform maintenance on the repository. You appear to be using Berkeley DB so you should also read the [Berkeley DB Recovery](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.recovery) chapter. You can download `svn` binaries from [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download).

**Update:** Latest releases of TortoiseSVN already bundle `svnadmin` and most other useful command-line utilities, thus you no longer need Slik SVN.